# Why do I get "wrong status line" errors from Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen-scraping, nokogiri

My Ruby/Nokogiri script is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

f = File.new("enterret" + ".txt", 'w')

1.upto(100) do |page|
  urltext = "http://xxxxxxx.com/" + "page/"
  urltext << page.to_s + "/"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(urltext))
  doc.css(".photoPost").each do |post|
    quote = post.css("h1 + p").text
    author = post.css("h1 + p + p").text
    f.puts "#{quote}" + "#{author}"
    f.puts "--------------------------------------------------------"
  end
end
```

When running this script i get the following error:

```
http.rb:2030:in `read_status_line': wrong status line: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"" (Net::HTTPBadResponse)
```

However my script writes to file correctly, it just that this error keeps coming up. What does the error mean?

Comment: Look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910816/how-can-i-parse-an-html-response-without-response-headers-using-ruby

Comment: Instead of the rigamarole you are using to create `urltext`, try: `urltext = "http://xxxxxxx.com/page/#{ page }/"`. It's more idiomatic when writing in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what site you are accessing it is hard to say for sure, but I suspect that the problem isn't in Nokogiri.

The error is being reported by `http.rb`, which would most likely be complaining about the HTTPd headers being returned. `http.rb` is concerned with the handshake with the HTTPd server and would whine about missing/malformed headers, but it wouldn't care about the payload.

Nokogiri, on the other hand, would be concerned about the payload, i.e., the HTML. The DOCTYPE is supposed to be part of the HTML payload, so I suspect their server is sending a HTML DOCTYPE instead of a MIME doctype, which should be `"text/html"`.

In the Ruby 1.8.7 http.rb file you'll see the following lines at 2030 in the code:

```
def response_class(code)
  CODE_TO_OBJ[code] or
  CODE_CLASS_TO_OBJ[code[0,1]] or
  HTTPUnknownResponse
end
```

That seems a likely place to generate the sort of message you're seeing.

Comment: thanks for the info, however i left my pc for a while and tried to re-run the script, and it worked flawlessly, without me changing a single line of the script. Interesting?

Comment: That just means the server stopped sending a bad response code. ie they fixed it.

Comment: I agree, they probably fixed the server. Sending a HTML doctype, instead of a mime doctype, is a grievous error, one that could really confuse any code that trusted the mime-type. Browsers often don't trust that information, since the developers learned long ago to not trust it; They can scan the output and see whether it's text, and look for tags and see if it's HTML. But most apps talking to a server won't do that and will assume the mime-type response is correct. Having written a lot of spiders over the years, I learned the hard way too, so for a spider I check to see what I got.